# Issue using 2 different recyclerView in 2 activities with 1 room database

Tags: java, android-activity, android-recyclerview, android-room

Good day - I'm new to recyclerViews and connecting to Room database. I've got one working with the help from a tutorial and now I want to add to it. My aim is to:

1. Implement a Room database which in turn presents data to the user via a recyclerView.
2. Have 1 recyclerView in the main activity and a 2nd recyclerView in a second activity. I'm trying to have a different layout in each activity as shown in the following links.

Main activity:

[image]

Second activity:

[image]

The issue I'm having is even though the XML files are unique for each activity, along with the variables within, the name of the recyclerView, and also the methods for each activity, the layout in the second activity shows in the first activity.

activity_main has the following:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view111"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="114dp"
    tools:listitem="@layout/testing" />
```

The second activity XML file has the following:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="488dp"
    tools:listitem="@layout/testing1_item" />
```

Can someone please help me identify why the same recyclerView is shown across the 2 activities please?

To trouble-shoot, I've:

- Gone through all the XML files to ensure there is no issue with the names of the files/methods etc.
- Copied the layout from the activity_main xml and applied it to the second xml file. This then in turn displayed the layout that I'm testing within in MainActivity across both activities.

MainActivity uses the activity_main.xml which uses a test file called testing.xml - code as follows:

MainActivity:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button); 

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllWordsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        RecyclerView recyclerView111 = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view111);
        recyclerView111.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView111.setHasFixedSize(true);

        NoteAdapter adapter = new NoteAdapter();
        recyclerView111.setAdapter(adapter);

        noteViewModel.getAllNotes().observe(this, new Observer<List<Note>>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Note> notes)
            {
               adapter.setNotes(notes);
            }
        });
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Open new Activity!"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view111"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="114dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/testing" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

testing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_priority1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textColorHighlight="@color/black"
            android:text="1"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_title1"
            android:layout_width="323dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="183dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/text_view_priority1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Title1"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_description1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/text_view_title1"
            android:text="Description1" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

The second activity is based on a class called AllWordsActivity" which uses activity_all_words which uses note_item test - code as follows:

AllWordsActivity.java

```
private NoteViewModel noteViewModel;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_words);


getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

NoteAdapter adapter = new NoteAdapter();
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

//noteViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NoteViewModel.class);
noteViewModel.getAllNotes().observe(this, new Observer<List<Note>>()
{
    @Override
    public void onChanged(List<Note> notes)
    {
        adapter.setNotes(notes);
    }
});
```

activity_all_words.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AllWordsActivity">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="488dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/note_item" />




</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

note_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_priority"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:textColor="@color/purple_500"
            android:text="1"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_title"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/text_view_priority"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_description"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/text_view_title"
            android:text="Description" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Code for noteAdapter:

````
```public class NoteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteAdapter.NoteHolder>
````

{
private List notes = new ArrayList<>();

````
@NonNull
@Override
public NoteHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.note_item, parent, false);
    return new NoteHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NoteHolder holder, int position)
{
    Note currentNote = notes.get(position);
    holder.textViewTitle.setText(currentNote.getTitle());
    holder.textViewDescription.setText(currentNote.getDescription());
    holder.textViewPriority.setText(String.valueOf(currentNote.getPriority()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return notes.size();
}

public void setNotes(List<Note> notes)
{
    this.notes = notes;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}```
````

Comment: What do you mean by "the name of the recyclerView, and also the methods for each activity, the layout in the second activity shows in the first activity."? What names and what methods? Please show the relevant code.

Comment: Hi @Code-Apprentice - I've pasted all relevant code in the description. Does this help?

Comment: What's the problem that you are seeing? What do you need help with?

Comment: Hello @Code-Apprentice - the problem is I have created 2 layouts for 2 activities however the layout from the 2nd activity shows across both activities. I've shown the 2 different layouts in the description (hyper-links). Let me know if this helps clarify.

Comment: What do you mean by " however the layout from the 2nd activity shows across both activities"? Add some screenshots to your question to show what each screen looks like and explain how you want it to be instead.

Comment: Hi @Code-Apprentice - I'm unable to add screenshots as I'm a new user. In the description of the issue I did include links to the screenshots which I can't repaste in this comment. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I edited your question so the images are embedded. I'm still unclear on what you need help with. How does each layout differ from what you want?

Comment: Hello @Code-Apprentice - my mistake for not being clear. The issue is I have created 2 layouts as shown - one for the main activity and for the second activity. When I run the application on an emulator, the layout for the second activity is displaying as expected and matching the screenshot - no issue here. The issue is with the main activity - a recyclerView appears but it is not matching the main activity layout file I have created. Instead I am seeing the recyclerView layout from the second activity displayed on the main activity. Please let me know if this helps explain the issue.

Comment: So you are seeing the same items in the RecyclerView in both activities. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that both activities use the same adapter for their list view: `NoteAdapter adapter = new NoteAdapter();`. In turn, `NoteAdapter` only inflates `note_item.xml` for each item in the list:

```
View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.note_item, parent, false);
```

To fix this, you need to either change `NoteAdapter` to work with multiple layout files for its rows. Or you need to create a different adapter for each `RecyclerView`.

**Original Answer:**

It sounds like you are seeing the same items displaying in both of your recycler views. The problem is that both the MainActivity and the AllWordsActivity have these lines:

```
        NoteAdapter adapter = new NoteAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        noteViewModel.getAllNotes().observe(this, new Observer<List<Note>>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Note> notes)
            {
               adapter.setNotes(notes);
            }
        });
```

So both activities are getting data from the same ViewModel to display. To display different data, use a different ViewModel in the MainActivity.

p.s. I suggest using consistent naming. You have `AllWordsActivity` and `NotesAdapater`. Either use `AllWords` or `Notes`, but don't mix and match.

Comment: Hello - thanks for your input. I do expect the contents to be the same across both activities as, as you have rightly pointed out, the same ViewModel is used. The issue remains that in Main Activity, I expect the a number on the left part of the recyclerView, title in the middle, and description on the right. However, the layout is ignored and I'm seeing the layout in the second activity in the Main Activity. The issue isn't about the data that's displayed but about how it is laid out in the 2 activities. (I'm not doing a job of explaining the issue it appears!)

Comment: @MrBrady I think I am getting closer to understand the problem. Let me restate to see if I do: you want different layouts for the items in the recycler view depending on which activity it is shown in. These layouts are defined in `testing.xml` and `note_item.xml` correct? Where do you inflate these layouts? I think it should be in `NoteAdapter`, right? If so, please edit your code to show the relevant parts of `NoteAdapter`.

Comment: @MrBrady On a tangent, why do you have two activities to show the same list of data? This seems like an overly complex UX to me.

Comment: Your understanding is correct - I want different layouts for the items depending on the activity used but this is not (currently) happening. I've added the requested code - I'm assuming a simple error but I just can't spot it.

Comment: As for the tangent question - I'm new to Android Studio and am experimenting with different elements to learn how things work, including the architecture. I wanted to understand how Room can be implemented and am practising with an app that would have, for example, a database full of reviews. The main activity would show the most recent review including all fields of the database - the second activity would show a recyclerView that presents a summary of each review in the database e.g. data, author, title. Welcome any advice on whether I should structure my test project in a better way.

Comment: @MrBrady It is common to design a UI the other way around: the first screen has a list of items, then when the user taps on one of the items, the next screen shows details of that particular item. The screen with the list can be implemented with a RecyclerView, but the detail screen can just be a layout with the appropriate widgets to display the details. This second screen doesn't need to be a RecyclerView.

Comment: @MrBrady With that said, I edited my question to include an explanation of why you see the behavior you are asking about. And I give a hint to a way to solve it, but I think in your case, you don't need two RecyclerViews. Instead, the "summary view" should just be widgets to display the details of a review.

p.s. I suggest you use names that describe what you are actually making. In this case, `review_item.xml` is more descriptive than `notes_item.xml` since you are making a review app, not a notes app. Similarly, rename `AllWordsActivity`, `testing.xml`, etc. to something more meaningful.

Comment: Hi @Code-Apprentice - thanks for your time and patience. I'll work through your suggestion around amending the adapter. One of the reasons I'd like to have all rows of the database on the mainActivity is I envisage creating a dashboard on the main screen (something to think through based on your feedback). In addition, I do need to tidy up the code, naming conventions, descriptions - this is something I'll be working through. Thanks again

Comment: @MrBrady What you are building here sounds like a "master/detail view". I meant to mention this in an earlier comment so you can google more about it if you want.

Comment: Thanks @Code-Apprentice - will look into the master/detail view suggested.

Comment: I resolved this issue by, as suggested, creating a different adapter for each activity.